# Can the android application package name contain non-english characters?

Tags: android, naming-conventions, package

Can the android application package name contain non-english characters?

for eg can it be com.android.नमस्ते

Before doing this I set eclipse to use UTF-8 (Windows->Preferences->General->workspace->Text encoding to UTF-8)

Comment: I don't know, but I should feel very cross if it couldn't. Symbols like punctuation are reasonable to ban, but letters like नमस्ते (or syllabics or ideograms for that matter) should be allowed by any civilised naming convention.

Comment: civlisation got nothing to do with it. It is just how it was designed. Like it or not, but obey the rules or you won't be able to build your package.

Comment: Of course it does, if it was designed badly then you have to live with that, but it that wouldn't stop it being a silly design to ban arbitrary letters for no reason.

Comment: Harkish. Have you tried compiling one like that to see what happens?

Comment: @JonHanna Have you tried reading android manual first?

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com nope, I have no idea about this, but find it interesting (and the question of accepted identifiers in modern computer langauges generally *very* interesting). Note how I don't offer an answer, but am +1ing yours for satisfying my curiousity.

Comment: Per this doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf the java language spec, page 166, java seems to allow non-ascii characters. Is my interpretation wrong?

Comment: @Harkish, Android supports Java 5 and most of Java 6, but not Java 7.

Comment: Tried using \uxxxx escape as in Java 5 spec http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/jls3.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Java package shall follow java package naming convention. See [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package)

Comment: How does the example in the question go against those conventions?

Comment: You ask about `com.android.नमस्ते`? It is invalid because it contains non-ascii characters: see: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: `c`, `o` and `m` are all ASCII, which is the only bit the link you give says should be ASCII.

Comment: Yes, and the prefix (`com` in this case) is spec'd as ASCII - and some other rules, while the rest is not.